# NodeJs crypto key create(google kms key import) NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, cryptojs, google-cloud-kms

i try import my pem key to Google KMS(with hsm support). I have google guide how it create with openssl:

---

Wrap the key
Generate a temporary random AES key that is 32 bytes long.

```
openssl rand -out temp_aes_key.bin 32
```

Wrap the temporary AES key with the wrapping public key using CKM_RSA_PKCS_OAEP.

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt
-pubin -inkey wrap_pub_key.pub
-in temp_aes_key.bin
-out temp_aes_key_wrapped.bin
-oaep
```

Wrap the target key with the temporary AES key using CKM_AES_KEY_WRAP_PAD.

```
openssl enc -id-aes256-wrap-pad  -K $( hexdump -v -e '/1
"%02x"' < "temp_aes_key.bin" )  -iv A65959A6  -in my_key.pem
-out target_key_wrapped.bin
```

Note the use of -iv A65959A6 sets A65959A6 as the Alternate Initial Value as required by the RFC 5649 specification.

I have wrap_pub_key.pub and my_key.pem, where wrap_pub_key.pub:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...........key...........
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

---

**How to programm this steps in nodeJs with cryto lib(without openssl)?**

Answer (score 1):

I think you are following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/wrapping-a-key) I'm not familiar with NodeJs, however I found the next documentation that It could be helpful,

I found the [github repo list](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries) of each language supported for the Cloud Platform services/APIs!

I think that you can start with this  available [examples](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/kms/latest/index.html#samples)

If you need more details you can use these references:

- [Google KMS Node.js io Samples](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-kms/tree/master/samples)
- [KMS Node.js Client Library](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/kms/latest/v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.html#encrypt)

Finally I understand that when you import this kind of key you need to choose a [key wrapping algorithms](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/key-wrapping#rsaes-oaep_with_sha-1_aes-kwp)

I hope you find this information helpful